# Reopen slow equipment question?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Who is responsible for slow equipment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/45037/2322)

This is closed as a duplicate, but I do not believe it is a duplicate.

The question is asking more or less how to work *around* the inability to request new equipment. The duplicate specifically addresses this point.

The closed question reason is amusing in light of the first line of the question:

---

[image]

---

Hoping to get some community votes to reopen it, those of us who work in large bureaucracies (with miles of red tape for requesting new hardware) can relate to this being very different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reopened by community vote.